# Can you determine the number of pages a Crystal Report will print to?

Tags: crystal-reports

A 3rd party application prints letters using Crystal Reports.

Our in-house style requires a footer graphic (approx 1.5 inches deep) at the bottom of the first page in any letter sent out.

Is there any way to determine the cut off point for the report detail sections that will always print the footer on the first page?

Some detail sections are either/or, some are optional and some are required.

There doesn't seem to be a mechanism for calculating the page length used if the maximum section length is chosen.

Is this a peculiarity of the way Crystal works or am I missing something?

Comment: The DETAILS section of a Crystal Report scales to fit the defined page size based on the confines of the header & footer.  So if you have a standard US letter page (8.5 x 11 inches), and define a header & footer that take up 2 inches each - the Details section gets the remaining 6.5 inches (it would be 7 if it weren't for margins).  I recommend dotjoe's answer to embed the graphic & conditionally handle the footer visibility but CR doesn't support all image file formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the graphic in the page footer. Add a suppress formula to the page footer

```
pagenumber <> 1
```

If you need a page footer for the other pages, you can add another page footer section below the first.

Comment: It's always the simple things that confuse you... I was looking for a MS Word style 'Different First Page' for the footer before I decided I'd need to calculate the sizes of the sections. This is perfect and I can't believe I didn't think of it (or that the original 'professional' report writer didn't!). Thanks.

Comment: yep, the page layout is all about the sections, suppress formulas, and the special keywords like _pagenumber_ and _onlastrecord_